# how to show name for this ID

Tags: php

I have a problem
not displayed the name for id

data base structure for category_list

```
id   name
1    php 
2    mysql
...  ...
10   html
```

and data base structure for entries

```
category_id
     8    
     5
```

for the results i have this code, this script displays the `ID`

as a result it shows 2 , but i want the following to be displayed: mysql

but I want to show `name` for this `ID` ,  instead of  `ID`

Comment: Please post the code on how you query and get the result

Comment: please post your tables structure and your query!

Comment: If your query already fetches data from category_list you may already have name in your $rows variable, otherwise you need to adjust your query to join with the category_list table. We need to see your code to help out.

Comment: `echo $rows['name'];` ?  Why would you expect to see something *other than* the ID when you output the ID?

Comment: @David the results that we obtained (`ID`) from line `<?php echo $rows['category_id']; ?>`  is right, I asked (i need help), how to do, when I write this line `<?php echo $rows['category_id']; ?>` i want to instead ID to show name, to be attributed to his ID

`$category = mysql_query("SELECT category_id FROM some_table");

<?php echo $rows['category_id']; ?>`

id and name is taken from the table (category_list) 
`SELECT * FROM `categories_list``

Comment: @prower: The answers below address exactly that.  Scroll down and take a look.  Basically, in order to display the name value on your page, you have to *get* that value from the database.

Answer (score 1):

We need to use a join query to get the category name for given id, e.g.:

```
select c.name 
from category_list c join entries e on c.id = e.category_id
where category_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your database query is something like this:

```
SELECT category_id FROM some_table
```

Thus, you're only selecting the ID, not the Name.  You can include the Name by joining the other table.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
    category_id,
    name
FROM
    some_table
    INNER JOIN category_list
        ON some_table.category_id = category_list.id
```

Then your results would also include the Name value, which you could output to the page:

```
echo $rows['name']
```

Comment: Hi,i try this code
`$client = mysql_query("SELECT category_id, name FROM some_table INNER JOIN category_list ON some_table.category_id = category_list.id");

$result = mysql_query($client);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$web_client = $row;

}`

`<?php echo $web_client['name']; ?>`

and i get error Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 
in line `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

Comment: @prower: Why are you calling `mysql_query()` *twice*?  Once you execute the query, you have the results.  You don't need to *execute the results*.  The error is telling you that your second `mysql_query()` failed.  Which makes sense, given that it's not trying to execute a query at all.

Comment: i tried many times , but frequently appears an error , into page i have multiple mysql_query,  the last modification is 
`$client = "SELECT category_id, name FROM get_category INNER JOIN category_list ON get_category.category_id = category_list.id";
$row = mysql_fetch_row($client);`
`<?php echo $row['name']; ?>`

Comment: but i have the error,
still don't  understand this line `SELECT category_id, name FROM get_category` in this table i have only  **category_id**  "This table is essential for work" , and I need to convert **id** into **name**, table with all category is **category_list** 
It would be very grateful if you have the correct code for me

Comment: @prower: Now you're not executing `mysql_query()` *at all*.  Why not?  In order to execute a SQL query, you have to *execute a SQL query*.  It really sounds like you should start with some introductory tutorials on PHP and MySQL.  You're missing some fundamental concepts here.  Just randomly typing code isn't going to get you very far.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php
i tried this
$client = mysql_query("SELECT category_id FROM get_category INNER JOIN category_list ON get_category.category_id = category_list.id");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($client);
anyway i have error Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Comment: @prower: That means the query is failing.  You have to check for errors after executing a SQL query.  Never assume that it succeeded.  mysql_error() should return the last error.

Comment: ok, after this row . mysql_error() , i get error  "Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous"  still don't understand this line `SELECT category_id, name FROM get_category` in this table i have only `category_id` " **This table is essential for work** " , and I need to convert `id` into `name`, table with all category is `category_list`

Comment: @prower: Please stop repeating how essential your work is.  Nobody here works for you.  As for the error, you're going to have to *look at your database structure* and *build a query to get the data you want*.  In this case you likely just need to prefix the `SELECT` items with their table names.  Something like `category_list.name` instead of `name`.  But seriously, go find some tutorials on PHP and MySQL.  You very clearly have *no idea* how PHP to SQL work, and I doubt your employer will appreciate the fact that you're just hoping strangers on the internet will do all of your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Run a second query pulling name from category_list like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM category_list WHERE id = '$rows['category_id']';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$category_name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $category_name['name'];
```

It would however be better to use a JOIN as others like David have pointed out.